# Upgrading old .Net 35 Project to 4.x -> Where do I download Reactive Framework 4.x

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Upgrading old .Net 35 Project to 4.x -> Where do I download Reactive Framework 4.x.

I looked here where MSDN forums pointed: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh242985.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Did not find DnLoad link?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is a 4.x yet. Latest stable in Nuget and [GitHub](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET) is 3.1.1.

Comment: I may not have been clear coming from .net 35 to 4.x

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just NuGet `System.Reactive` so get the latest bits in your project.

Comment: The NuGet packages have been renamed with the introduction of version 3, see https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Rx-*` packages have been frozen at 2.2.5 because the packages themselves require breaking changes to support .NET Core. And rather than bumping the major version, they've decided to start fresh with `System.Reactive*` naming.

You can simply use the PM console:

```
Install-Package System.Reactive
```

You will need an updated version of the nuget package installer to be able to parse the 3.x packages. Here's the [release announcement](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/releases/tag/v3.0.0).